# Ubuntu 18.04 Error: No video mode activated

Tags: 18.04, grub2

my Ubuntu stuck at this page after booting up. There's no log in to the desktop at all.

[Stucked on this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWFFT.png)

Anybody able to help me in this?

Comment: Again, I don't really understand this will to use VMware when virtualbox really has no issues at all with ubuntu and allows for many more things with easy-out-of-the-box usablility such as shared copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get get back into desktop. Tried lots of ways people suggested by commenting out some GRUB stuff or command line to update. However, those doesn't work for me.

Got a temporary fix for my case whereby, when starting up Ubuntu on VMware, when you see Oracle's logo, click on the screen for focus and hold onto SHIFT until Grub menu appears.

On Grub menu, navigate to Advance Options and click on the recovery mode. From there, click update Grub and you're good to go. Reboot your Ubuntu and it will work.

Note that this fix is only **TEMPORARY**. When you able to get back into the desktop, do a snapshot first and try other method of fixing it. Whenever you restart or shutdown, it will go back to the same error again.

Currently, my Ubuntu is not able to boot up in full screen like before. Still trying to find ways to fix it.